# How to combine common data in JSON object of Map()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, merge

I have some JSON Data Like This:

```
{
        "+2555970315763":{
            "uid": "u9weKk62GvXu4Yf66HM2TFXDL5S2",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555970315763",
            "lastTime": "Mon, 14 Feb 2022 09:40:32 GMT"
        },
        "+2555970605736":{
            "uid": "n3qGtqMWqVXGyZMSFz7HqwtfTDB3",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555970605736",
            "lastTime": "Mon, 14 Feb 2022 05:32:53 GMT"
        },
        "+2555973055799":{
            "uid": "hGHq2TLCkeWsCWOZ0KdSI6mKbvp2",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555973055799",
            "lastTime": "Mon, 21 Feb 2022 05:25:46 GMT",
            "usage": [
                {
                    "firstTime": "18:04:34",
                    "count": 1,
                    "date": "2022-02-19"
                },
                {
                    "firstTime": "14:53:08",
                    "count": 6,
                    "date": "2022-02-21"
                },
                {
                    "count": 4,
                    "date": "2022-02-22",
                    "firstTime": "12:53:56"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2022-02-25",
                    "count": 4,
                    "firstTime": "12:12:03"
                },
                {
                    "firstTime": "12:35:04",
                    "date": "2022-02-26",
                    "count": 34
                },
                {
                    "count": 31,
                    "firstTime": "11:32:03",
                    "date": "2022-02-27"
                }
            ]
        },
        "+2555974235764":{
            "uid": "uUWJvN5XVwWGfNiC6UuwlmVVTO73",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555974235764",
            "lastTime": "Wed, 16 Feb 2022 06:04:54 GMT",
            "usage": [
                {
                    "count": 2,
                    "date": "2022-02-16",
                    "firstTime": "12:15:38"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2022-02-17",
                    "firstTime": "11:45:19",
                    "count": 43
                },
                {
                    "count": 148,
                    "firstTime": "11:33:53",
                    "date": "2022-02-19"
                },
                {
                    "count": 127,
                    "firstTime": "11:42:46",
                    "date": "2022-02-20",
                    "dow": "Sunday"
                },
                {
                    "firstTime": "12:18:28",
                    "count": 42,
                    "date": "2022-02-22",
                }
            ]
        },
        "+2555979295712":{
            "uid": "Cx63RRHQYpMMwfAbi0ebqledk5G3",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555979295712",
            "lastTime": "Tue, 01 Mar 2022 13:18:23 GMT",
        },
        "+2555970875726":{
            "uid": "I5I3SFgZT3MAxomDHrPGq17OMcO2",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555970875726",
            "lastTime": "Tue, 01 Mar 2022 15:43:43 GMT",
        },
        "+2555970125770":{
            "uid": "y9IcP0S6uHcOjPk0deXbuXZC4VA3",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555970125770",
            "lastTime": "Tue, 25 Jan 2022 09:38:27 GMT",
        },
        "+2555970335754":{
            "uid": "gS2RkZdBlHZNOIYQUXB1iPfOkQ33",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555970335754",
            "lastTime": "Fri, 18 Feb 2022 07:40:32 GMT",
        },
        "+2555974475787":{
            "uid": "QfSNsAMob8SXYWFB8TmgC0WMAXY2",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555974475787",
            "lastTime": "Fri, 11 Feb 2022 08:44:47 GMT",
        },
        "+2555974725740":{
            "uid": "9y4unCW5PHRA0AjcVZdHFXh9thy1",
            "phoneNumber": "+2555974725740",
            "lastTime": "Mon, 21 Feb 2022 13:57:27 GMT",
        }
    }
```

I want to merge some of the `phonenumber` data like `+2555973055799` and `+2555974235764`, I the for example: they both have objects with `date`:`2022-02-19` so, the resultant object after merging should be like:

```
{
    "firstTime": "11:33:53",
    "count": 149,
    "date": "2022-02-19"
},
```

count should be sum of both objects from phonenumbers ad `firstTime` should be time which is first. and `uid`, `phone number` should be concatinated, lastTime should be which is greater of two times?

The remaining phonenumbers data should be unchanged, only these two objects data should be merged,

How should I do that?

can anyone please help with this?

Comment: It will be helpful if you write expected answer manually

Comment: just merge data on same dates, with given phoneNumbers, that's it

Comment: @sina I think Kerry meant for you to fill in the full expected output instead of describing it, which is really helpful

Comment: If I just look at the current question, I could write a method that compares phone numbers and combines date data, but I don't know if you want this combined data object, or if you need to adjust the raw JSON data

Comment: @lan: I want it as a data object, It's just as you said, I want it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand your question correctly, but let's give it a try.

So, you would like to merge datas according to the date of usage. If 2 or more json objects was used on the same date, then you would like to to see the date, count and first time of use of these datas?

EDIT:

So, i created a prototype.

Maybe it is a little bit complicated solution, but i think it is good for a start.
I separated every object with usage data, then i looked for date duplicates, i stored both uid and the same date. Then i looked up for the count's and compared the firstTime datas and everything stored in the result variable.

Check console log for result.

```
    var result = [] // we will store the result here

    var dataWithUsage = [];
    for (var i in obj) // iterate thru every data
        if (obj[i].usage)  // if data has usage property
        {
            dataWithUsage.push(obj[i]) // separate it from the main data structure
        }

    // console.log(dataWithUsage)

    var usages = [] // we will collect every usage here
    dataWithUsage.forEach(data => {
        // console.log(data.usage, data.uid)
        data.usage.forEach(element => {
            usages.push({ date: element.date, uid: data.uid })
        });
    });
    // console.log(usages)

    // we will compare every usage and we try to do it only once
    for (let i = 0; i < usages.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < usages.length; j++) {
            // console.log(usages[i], "vs" , usages[j])
            if (usages[i].date == usages[j].date) {
                result.push({ date: usages[i].date, uid1: usages[i].uid, uid2: usages[j].uid })
            }
        }
    }

    // at this point in the results we have our uid's with dates. Now we can do the data merge        
    result.forEach(element => {
        var uid1Index = dataWithUsage.findIndex(object => object.uid == element.uid1)
        var uid2Index = dataWithUsage.findIndex(object => object.uid == element.uid2) // we got the 2 objects for data merge

        var count = 0
        var firstTime

        let usageIndexofuid1 = dataWithUsage[uid1Index].usage.findIndex(elem => elem.date == element.date)
        let usageIndexofuid2 = dataWithUsage[uid2Index].usage.findIndex(elem => elem.date == element.date)

        count = dataWithUsage[uid1Index].usage[usageIndexofuid1].count + dataWithUsage[uid2Index].usage[usageIndexofuid2].count

        // console.log(dataWithUsage[uid1Index].usage[usageIndexofuid1].firstTime, dataWithUsage[uid2Index].usage[usageIndexofuid2].firstTime)
        // console.log(dataWithUsage[uid1Index].usage[usageIndexofuid1].firstTime > dataWithUsage[uid2Index].usage[usageIndexofuid2].firstTime)

        firstTime = ((dataWithUsage[uid1Index].usage[usageIndexofuid1].firstTime < dataWithUsage[uid2Index].usage[usageIndexofuid2].firstTime) ? dataWithUsage[uid1Index].usage[usageIndexofuid1].firstTime : dataWithUsage[uid2Index].usage[usageIndexofuid2].firstTime)

        // console.log(firstTime,"fistTime")
        // console.log(count,"count")

        element.count = count
        element.firstTime = firstTime


    });


    console.log("result")
    console.log(result)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/peaq6cb3/

Comment: yes, exactly, but on same date but the phone numbers that we mentioned. The remaining data of different dates should be intact.